# How to access API plateform properties from react

Tags: json, reactjs, symfony, api-platform.com

After a request to a symfony API platform they return me properties like this:

```json
@context: "/api/contexts/User"
@id: "/api/users"
@type: "hydra:Collection"
hydra:member: Array(2)
0: "Création de compte enregistrée."
1: {@id: "/api/users/3", @type: "User", id: 3, email: "*******@outlook.com", firstname: "******", …}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
hydra:totalItems: 2
__proto__: Object
```

But I can't access to the `hydra: member` properties from react JavaScript.

Comment: It is not a React thing as far as I can tell http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/

Comment: The react branches of [my tutorial](https://github.com/metaclass-nl/tutorial-api-platform) contain generated es6 code including for paginated results containing hydra:member. I recently tested it with api platform 2.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access object properties with symbols like this: `object['hydra:member']`. Same thing with `@id`, `@type`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, but i have already try this solution with axios response, and was not work

Comment: I have try to convert json object to array and react return me an error

Comment: @Jud3v Why convert it?, `hydra:member` already contains an array of objects.

Comment: Thanks I use angular:  `this.totalQuestions = results['hydra:totalItems'];`